# Parsing a URI to extract query parameters, with Dart

Tags: dart, dart-html

I have a request in this form:

```
http://website/index.html?name=MyName&token=12345
```

Is there a way how to extract name and token from this url? There is always an option to iterate through all characters and save it that way, but I am looking for more elegant solution in Dart.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```dart
var uri = Uri.parse('http://website/index.html?name=MyName&token=12345');
uri.queryParameters.forEach((k, v) {
   print('key: $k - value: $v');
});
```

```dart
key: name - value: MyName
key: token - value: 12345
```

Comment: Hi Günter Zöchbauer, can you suggest a solution for this -/http://1X.13X.X4.1XX:1000/report/DeleteFile?file=GA55-Estimated-NEHRU-LAL-2021-2022.pdf  and i try to pass this  fileNameGa = ga55estimated+"-NEHRU-LAL-" +year.toString() + "-"  + year.toString() + ".pdf"; as query params getting this error og linked dynamic.

Comment: paasing this - final queryParameters = {
   'file': fileNameGa,
    };