# Flutter web Bottom Navigation Bar with url updating and hyperlink support

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have been searching around for ages online for an example of a flutter app that supports the following:

1. Persistent bottom navigation bar
2. Navigator support for each bottom navigation bar item that persists state
3. Navigators update the URL in flutter web on navigation
4. Navigators support hyperlinking to a specific page in flutter web. For example if a user types [www.myappdomain.com/#/profile](http://www.myappdomain.com/#/profile) they get navigated to the profile page. Or they type [www.myappdomain.com/#/profile?id=123](http://www.myappdomain.com/#/profile?id=123) they get navigated to the profile page for user 123.

I've been able to achieve points 1 and 2 with the following code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(BaseApp());
}

class BaseApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BaseAppState createState() => _BaseAppState();
}

class _BaseAppState extends State<BaseApp> {
  // define all navigation tabs for user
  static List<NavigationTabModel> _navigationTabs = [
    NavigationTabModel(
      title: 'Home',
      icon: Icons.home,
      url: '/home',
      navigatorKey: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    ),
    NavigationTabModel(
      title: 'Search',
      icon: Icons.search,
      url: '/search',
      navigatorKey: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    ),
    NavigationTabModel(
      title: 'Profile',
      icon: Icons.person,
      url: '/profile',
      navigatorKey: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    ),
  ];

  // route generator used to build all material page routes
  RouteGenerator _routeGenerator = RouteGenerator();

  // set the current tab to the home page
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  void _select(int index) {
    if (index == _currentIndex) {
      // case 1 - if user presses on currently selected tab
      // pop to first route - i.e. ensure no routes are over laid on top of the current route
      _navigationTabs[_currentIndex]
          .navigatorKey
          .currentState
          .popUntil((route) {
        return route.isFirst;
      });
    } else {
      // case 2 - user selects any other tab
      // rebuild application state with the newly selected navigation tab
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
      });
    }
  }

  /// generate a list of navigators that will have their state persisted in an
  /// indexed stack.
  List<Widget> _getPersistantStack() {
    return _navigationTabs.map((tab) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return !await tab.navigatorKey.currentState.maybePop();
        },
        child: Navigator(
          key: tab.navigatorKey,
          initialRoute: tab.url,
          onGenerateRoute: _routeGenerator.generateRoute,
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// ********************* HOLD POINT *********************
    /// MaterialApp contains our top-level Navigator. Top level navigator is
    /// required to enable navigation via urls in flutter web. Likely that this
    /// section requires refractoring in some way to enable url updates from the
    /// nested navigators and hyperlinking from web browsers to specific pages
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: IndexedStack(
            children: _getPersistantStack(),
            index: _currentIndex,
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: _navigationTabs.map((tab) {
            return BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: tab.title,
              icon: Icon(tab.icon),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onTap: (int index) {
            _select(index);
          },
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          // hide titles on navigation bar
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NavigationTabModel {
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final String url;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  NavigationTabModel({
    this.title,
    this.icon,
    this.url,
    this.navigatorKey,
  });
}

class RouteGenerator {
  Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    // Widget builder (function that returns a widget) to construct the route page
    WidgetBuilder builder;

    // build different route (page) based on the route passed to the navigator
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/home':
        builder = (BuildContext context) {
          return SamplePage(name: 'home');
        };
        break;
      case '/search':
        builder = (BuildContext context) {
          return SamplePage(name: 'search');
        };
        break;
      case '/profile':
        builder = (BuildContext context) {
          return SamplePage(name: 'profile');
        };
        break;
      case '/':
        builder = null;
        break;
      default:
        // If there is no such named route in the switch statement
        builder = (BuildContext context) {
          return SamplePage();
        };
    }
    // prevent page being added to default '/' route
    if (builder == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: builder,
      settings: settings,
    );
  }
}

class SamplePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;

  SamplePage({
    this.name,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('$name'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('push new route'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/$name');
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 16,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 100,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: Text(
                      index.toString(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However I cannot figure out how to update this app to achieve points 3 and 4. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While Navigator 2.0 is a bit intimidating at first, it is well worth it when you are (mainly) targeting web apps, because you have a lot of options for restoring state from a deep link.

In the [official introduction](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade) which @Lulupointu already linked to, there is an example with exactly what you are looking for (but a bit hidden at the very bottom of the article).

[In this gist](https://gist.github.com/johnpryan/bbca91e23bbb4d39247fa922533be7c9) is a working example for using different Navigator Stacks for different tabs, which for completeness I post below. It works for me on Channel beta, 1.23.0-18.1.pre

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(NestedRouterDemo());
}

class Book {
  final String title;
  final String author;

  Book(this.title, this.author);
}

class NestedRouterDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NestedRouterDemoState createState() => _NestedRouterDemoState();
}

class _NestedRouterDemoState extends State<NestedRouterDemo> {
  BookRouterDelegate _routerDelegate = BookRouterDelegate();
  BookRouteInformationParser _routeInformationParser =
      BookRouteInformationParser();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Books App',
      routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
      routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
    );
  }
}

class BooksAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _selectedIndex;

  Book _selectedBook;

  final List<Book> books = [
    Book('Stranger in a Strange Land', 'Robert A. Heinlein'),
    Book('Foundation', 'Isaac Asimov'),
    Book('Fahrenheit 451', 'Ray Bradbury'),
  ];

  BooksAppState() : _selectedIndex = 0;

  int get selectedIndex => _selectedIndex;

  set selectedIndex(int idx) {
    _selectedIndex = idx;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Book get selectedBook => _selectedBook;

  set selectedBook(Book book) {
    _selectedBook = book;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getSelectedBookById() {
    if (!books.contains(_selectedBook)) return 0;
    return books.indexOf(_selectedBook);
  }

  void setSelectedBookById(int id) {
    if (id < 0 || id > books.length - 1) {
      return;
    }

    _selectedBook = books[id];
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class BookRouteInformationParser extends RouteInformationParser<BookRoutePath> {
  @override
  Future<BookRoutePath> parseRouteInformation(
      RouteInformation routeInformation) async {
    final uri = Uri.parse(routeInformation.location);

    if (uri.pathSegments.isNotEmpty && uri.pathSegments.first == 'settings') {
      return BooksSettingsPath();
    } else {
      if (uri.pathSegments.length >= 2) {
        if (uri.pathSegments[0] == 'book') {
          return BooksDetailsPath(int.tryParse(uri.pathSegments[1]));
        }
      }
      return BooksListPath();
    }
  }

  @override
  RouteInformation restoreRouteInformation(BookRoutePath configuration) {
    if (configuration is BooksListPath) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/home');
    }
    if (configuration is BooksSettingsPath) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/settings');
    }
    if (configuration is BooksDetailsPath) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/book/${configuration.id}');
    }
    return null;
  }
}

class BookRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<BookRoutePath>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<BookRoutePath> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  BooksAppState appState = BooksAppState();

  BookRouterDelegate() : navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>() {
    appState.addListener(notifyListeners);
  }

  @override
  BookRoutePath get currentConfiguration {
    if (appState.selectedIndex == 1) {
      return BooksSettingsPath();
    } else {
      if (appState.selectedBook == null) {
        return BooksListPath();
      } else {
        return BooksDetailsPath(appState.getSelectedBookById());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        MaterialPage(
          child: AppShell(appState: appState),
        ),
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        if (!route.didPop(result)) {
          return false;
        }

        if (appState.selectedBook != null) {
          appState.selectedBook = null;
        }
        notifyListeners();
        return true;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(BookRoutePath path) async {
    if (path is BooksListPath) {
      appState.selectedIndex = 0;
      appState.selectedBook = null;
    } else if (path is BooksSettingsPath) {
      appState.selectedIndex = 1;
    } else if (path is BooksDetailsPath) {
      appState.selectedIndex = 0;
      appState.setSelectedBookById(path.id);
    }
  }
}

// Routes
abstract class BookRoutePath {}

class BooksListPath extends BookRoutePath {}

class BooksSettingsPath extends BookRoutePath {}

class BooksDetailsPath extends BookRoutePath {
  final int id;

  BooksDetailsPath(this.id);
}

// Widget that contains the AdaptiveNavigationScaffold
class AppShell extends StatefulWidget {
  final BooksAppState appState;

  AppShell({
    @required this.appState,
  });

  @override
  _AppShellState createState() => _AppShellState();
}

class _AppShellState extends State<AppShell> {
  InnerRouterDelegate _routerDelegate;
  ChildBackButtonDispatcher _backButtonDispatcher;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _routerDelegate = InnerRouterDelegate(widget.appState);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant AppShell oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _routerDelegate.appState = widget.appState;
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    // Defer back button dispatching to the child router
    _backButtonDispatcher = Router.of(context)
        .backButtonDispatcher
        .createChildBackButtonDispatcher();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = widget.appState;

    // Claim priority, If there are parallel sub router, you will need
    // to pick which one should take priority;
    _backButtonDispatcher.takePriority();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Router(
        routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
        backButtonDispatcher: _backButtonDispatcher,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: 'Settings'),
        ],
        currentIndex: appState.selectedIndex,
        onTap: (newIndex) {
          appState.selectedIndex = newIndex;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InnerRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<BookRoutePath>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<BookRoutePath> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  BooksAppState get appState => _appState;
  BooksAppState _appState;
  set appState(BooksAppState value) {
    if (value == _appState) {
      return;
    }
    _appState = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  InnerRouterDelegate(this._appState);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        if (appState.selectedIndex == 0) ...[
          FadeAnimationPage(
            child: BooksListScreen(
              books: appState.books,
              onTapped: _handleBookTapped,
            ),
            key: ValueKey('BooksListPage'),
          ),
          if (appState.selectedBook != null)
            MaterialPage(
              key: ValueKey(appState.selectedBook),
              child: BookDetailsScreen(book: appState.selectedBook),
            ),
        ] else
          FadeAnimationPage(
            child: SettingsScreen(),
            key: ValueKey('SettingsPage'),
          ),
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        appState.selectedBook = null;
        notifyListeners();
        return route.didPop(result);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(BookRoutePath path) async {
    // This is not required for inner router delegate because it does not
    // parse route
    assert(false);
  }

  void _handleBookTapped(Book book) {
    appState.selectedBook = book;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class FadeAnimationPage extends Page {
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimationPage({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  Route createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      settings: this,
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, animation2) {
        var curveTween = CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn);
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation.drive(curveTween),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// Screens
class BooksListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Book> books;
  final ValueChanged<Book> onTapped;

  BooksListScreen({
    @required this.books,
    @required this.onTapped,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          for (var book in books)
            ListTile(
              title: Text(book.title),
              subtitle: Text(book.author),
              onTap: () => onTapped(book),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BookDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Book book;

  BookDetailsScreen({
    @required this.book,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('Back'),
            ),
            if (book != null) ...[
              Text(book.title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
              Text(book.author, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1),
            ],
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Settings screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want the Home Navigation Button to link to the homepage and not keep the state, then you have to replace set selectedIndex with this:

```
  set selectedIndex(int idx) {
    _selectedIndex = idx;
    if (_selectedIndex == 1) {
      // Remove this line if you want to keep the selected book when navigating
      // between "settings" and "home" which book was selected when Settings is
      // tapped.
      selectedBook = null;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

You might want to take a look at how to extract query parameters, when writing your own RouteInformationParser:
[Parsing a URI to extract query parameters, with Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573567/parsing-a-uri-to-extract-query-parameters-with-dart)

Here is another example you might want to take a look at for understanding Navigator 2.0: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/63424

Comment: Great thanks for the information! :) I did actually have a look at this example from the original answer provided by @Lulupointu. And while it does achieve a persisting state bottom navigation bar with URL updating, it has issues with deep linking. For example if I was on the /settings route, then typed /book/1 the book route does not load. Any ideas on how that example might be updated to fix this issue?

Comment: just fixed this in the answer above - the problem was in the `setNewRoutePath` method - when parsing a detail page, the global app state for which tab you are in was not updated. You may also want to add a 'pop' command on the BottomBarButtons as a way of moving backwards in the stack (the new Apple Music app is a wonderful example on how this can be done)

Comment: this is awesome! everything appears to be working now with the exception of one minor thing which is the browser history generated by this application does not show the entire URL of each navigated page like a typical website would, instead it just shows the app name, which in this case is 'Books App'. Also on a side note do you happen to know if Google will index all the pages of the app correctly when configured like this?

Comment: I also tried adding the navigator.pop() method to the bottom navigation bar, as suggested but it causes some strange behaviour with the application. `onTap: (newIndex) { appState.selectedIndex = newIndex; Navigator.of(context).pop(); }`

Comment: As of now Flutter apps are not SEO friendly so I doubt that any of the pages are indexed by their crawlers (that may change soon), but that would be a great new question on stack overflow so others can find it too ;) - regarding the strange behaviour, I would also suggest opening a new question, but I'm happy to continue the conversation elsewhere (find me on twitter, DMs are open). 
If my answer solves your initial question, it would be great if you could accept it and award the bounty :)

Comment: is it possible to keep state of the pages after switching to other tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Since the 30/09/2020, [flutter introduced **Navigator 2.0**](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade).

You can check the link for the complete tutorial. Skip the part about Navigator 1.0 and go to Navigator 2.0.

Basically the two main widget are the `RouteInformationParser` and the `RouterDelegate`.

I would strongly advise reading the article for this and a lot of other information about routing.

That said, here is the code which they describe, you can try it in the web and see that it achieves your point 3 and 4.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(BooksApp());
}

class Book {
  final String title;
  final String author;

  Book(this.title, this.author);
}

class BooksApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _BooksAppState();
}

class _BooksAppState extends State<BooksApp> {
  BookRouterDelegate _routerDelegate = BookRouterDelegate();
  BookRouteInformationParser _routeInformationParser =
  BookRouteInformationParser();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Books App',
      routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
      routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
    );
  }
}

class BookRouteInformationParser extends RouteInformationParser<BookRoutePath> {
  @override
  Future<BookRoutePath> parseRouteInformation(
      RouteInformation routeInformation) async {
    final uri = Uri.parse(routeInformation.location);
    // Handle '/'
    if (uri.pathSegments.length == 0) {
      return BookRoutePath.home();
    }

    // Handle '/book/:id'
    if (uri.pathSegments.length == 2) {
      if (uri.pathSegments[0] != 'book') return BookRoutePath.unknown();
      var remaining = uri.pathSegments[1];
      var id = int.tryParse(remaining);
      if (id == null) return BookRoutePath.unknown();
      return BookRoutePath.details(id);
    }

    // Handle unknown routes
    return BookRoutePath.unknown();
  }

  @override
  RouteInformation restoreRouteInformation(BookRoutePath path) {
    if (path.isUnknown) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/404');
    }
    if (path.isHomePage) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/');
    }
    if (path.isDetailsPage) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/book/${path.id}');
    }
    return null;
  }
}

class BookRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<BookRoutePath>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<BookRoutePath> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  Book _selectedBook;
  bool show404 = false;

  List<Book> books = [
    Book('Stranger in a Strange Land', 'Robert A. Heinlein'),
    Book('Foundation', 'Isaac Asimov'),
    Book('Fahrenheit 451', 'Ray Bradbury'),
  ];

  BookRouterDelegate() : navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  BookRoutePath get currentConfiguration {
    if (show404) {
      return BookRoutePath.unknown();
    }
    return _selectedBook == null
        ? BookRoutePath.home()
        : BookRoutePath.details(books.indexOf(_selectedBook));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        MaterialPage(
          key: ValueKey('BooksListPage'),
          child: BooksListScreen(
            books: books,
            onTapped: _handleBookTapped,
          ),
        ),
        if (show404)
          MaterialPage(key: ValueKey('UnknownPage'), child: UnknownScreen())
        else if (_selectedBook != null)
          BookDetailsPage(book: _selectedBook)
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        if (!route.didPop(result)) {
          return false;
        }

        // Update the list of pages by setting _selectedBook to null
        _selectedBook = null;
        show404 = false;
        notifyListeners();

        return true;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(BookRoutePath path) async {
    if (path.isUnknown) {
      _selectedBook = null;
      show404 = true;
      return;
    }

    if (path.isDetailsPage) {
      if (path.id < 0 || path.id > books.length - 1) {
        show404 = true;
        return;
      }

      _selectedBook = books[path.id];
    } else {
      _selectedBook = null;
    }

    show404 = false;
  }

  void _handleBookTapped(Book book) {
    _selectedBook = book;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class BookDetailsPage extends Page {
  final Book book;

  BookDetailsPage({
    this.book,
  }) : super(key: ValueKey(book));

  Route createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: this,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return BookDetailsScreen(book: book);
      },
    );
  }
}

class BookRoutePath {
  final int id;
  final bool isUnknown;

  BookRoutePath.home()
      : id = null,
        isUnknown = false;

  BookRoutePath.details(this.id) : isUnknown = false;

  BookRoutePath.unknown()
      : id = null,
        isUnknown = true;

  bool get isHomePage => id == null;

  bool get isDetailsPage => id != null;
}

class BooksListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Book> books;
  final ValueChanged<Book> onTapped;

  BooksListScreen({
    @required this.books,
    @required this.onTapped,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          for (var book in books)
            ListTile(
              title: Text(book.title),
              subtitle: Text(book.author),
              onTap: () => onTapped(book),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BookDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Book book;

  BookDetailsScreen({
    @required this.book,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            if (book != null) ...[
              Text(book.title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
              Text(book.author, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1),
            ],
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UnknownScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('404!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the information! While this does achieve points 3 and 4, the difficult part is to then amalgamate that with the rest of the required functionality, i.e. a bottom navigation bar with state persistence? any guidance on how I might achieve that? Also after reading this article navigator 2.0 seem unnecessarily complicated...

Answer (score 1):

A working bottom nav from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/johnpryan/bbca91e23bbb4d39247fa922533be7c9) compatible with flutter sdk >= 2.12

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(NestedRouterDemo());
}

class Book {
  final String title;
  final String author;

  Book(this.title, this.author);
}

class NestedRouterDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NestedRouterDemoState createState() => _NestedRouterDemoState();
}

class _NestedRouterDemoState extends State<NestedRouterDemo> {
  BookRouterDelegate _routerDelegate = BookRouterDelegate();
  BookRouteInformationParser _routeInformationParser = BookRouteInformationParser();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Books App',
      routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
      routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
    );
  }
}

class BooksAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _selectedIndex;

  Book? _selectedBook;

  final List<Book> books = [
    Book('Stranger in a Strange Land', 'Robert A. Heinlein'),
    Book('Foundation', 'Isaac Asimov'),
    Book('Fahrenheit 451', 'Ray Bradbury'),
  ];

  BooksAppState() : _selectedIndex = 0;

  int get selectedIndex => _selectedIndex;

  set selectedIndex(int idx) {
    _selectedIndex = idx;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Book? get selectedBook => _selectedBook;

  set selectedBook(Book? book) {
    _selectedBook = book;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int? getSelectedBookById() {
    if (_selectedBook == null || !books.contains(_selectedBook)) return null;
    return books.indexOf(_selectedBook!);
  }

  void setSelectedBookById(int id) {
    if (id < 0 || id > books.length - 1) {
      return;
    }

    _selectedBook = books[id];
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class BookRouteInformationParser extends RouteInformationParser<BookRoutePath> {
  @override
  Future<BookRoutePath> parseRouteInformation(RouteInformation routeInformation) async {
    final uri = Uri.parse(routeInformation.location ?? '');

    if (uri.pathSegments.isNotEmpty && uri.pathSegments.first == 'settings') {
      return BooksSettingsPath();
    } else {
      if (uri.pathSegments.length >= 2) {
        if (uri.pathSegments[0] == 'book') {
          return BooksDetailsPath(int.tryParse(uri.pathSegments[1]));
        }
      }
      return BooksListPath();
    }
  }

  @override
  RouteInformation restoreRouteInformation(BookRoutePath configuration) {
    if (configuration is BooksListPath) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/home');
    }
    if (configuration is BooksSettingsPath) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/settings');
    }
    if (configuration is BooksDetailsPath) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/book/${configuration.id}');
    }
    return RouteInformation();
  }
}

class BookRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<BookRoutePath>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<BookRoutePath> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  BooksAppState appState = BooksAppState();

  BookRouterDelegate() : navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>() {
    appState.addListener(notifyListeners);
  }

  BookRoutePath get currentConfiguration {
    if (appState.selectedIndex == 1) {
      return BooksSettingsPath();
    } else {
      if (appState.selectedBook == null) {
        return BooksListPath();
      } else {
        return BooksDetailsPath(appState.getSelectedBookById());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        MaterialPage(
          child: AppShell(appState: appState),
        ),
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        if (!route.didPop(result)) {
          return false;
        }

        if (appState.selectedBook != null) {
          appState.selectedBook = null;
        }
        notifyListeners();
        return true;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(BookRoutePath path) async {
    if (path is BooksListPath) {
      appState.selectedIndex = 0;
      appState.selectedBook = null;
    } else if (path is BooksSettingsPath) {
      appState.selectedIndex = 1;
    } else if (path is BooksDetailsPath && path.id != null) {
      appState.setSelectedBookById(path.id!);
    }
  }
}

// Routes
abstract class BookRoutePath {}

class BooksListPath extends BookRoutePath {}

class BooksSettingsPath extends BookRoutePath {}

class BooksDetailsPath extends BookRoutePath {
  final int? id;

  BooksDetailsPath(this.id);
}

// Widget that contains the AdaptiveNavigationScaffold
class AppShell extends StatefulWidget {
  final BooksAppState appState;

  AppShell({
    required this.appState,
  });

  @override
  _AppShellState createState() => _AppShellState();
}

class _AppShellState extends State<AppShell> {
  late InnerRouterDelegate _routerDelegate;
  late ChildBackButtonDispatcher _backButtonDispatcher;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _routerDelegate = InnerRouterDelegate(widget.appState);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant AppShell oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _routerDelegate.appState = widget.appState;
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    // Defer back button dispatching to the child router
    _backButtonDispatcher = Router.of(context).backButtonDispatcher!.createChildBackButtonDispatcher();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = widget.appState;

    // Claim priority, If there are parallel sub router, you will need
    // to pick which one should take priority;
    _backButtonDispatcher.takePriority();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Router(
        routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
        backButtonDispatcher: _backButtonDispatcher,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: 'Settings'),
        ],
        currentIndex: appState.selectedIndex,
        onTap: (newIndex) {
          appState.selectedIndex = newIndex;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InnerRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<BookRoutePath>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<BookRoutePath> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  BooksAppState get appState => _appState;
  BooksAppState _appState;
  set appState(BooksAppState value) {
    if (value == _appState) {
      return;
    }
    _appState = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  InnerRouterDelegate(this._appState);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        if (appState.selectedIndex == 0) ...[
          FadeAnimationPage(
            child: BooksListScreen(
              books: appState.books,
              onTapped: _handleBookTapped,
            ),
            key: ValueKey('BooksListPage'),
          ),
          if (appState.selectedBook != null)
            MaterialPage(
              key: ValueKey(appState.selectedBook),
              child: BookDetailsScreen(book: appState.selectedBook!),
            ),
        ] else
          FadeAnimationPage(
            child: SettingsScreen(),
            key: ValueKey('SettingsPage'),
          ),
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        appState.selectedBook = null;
        notifyListeners();
        return route.didPop(result);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(BookRoutePath path) async {
    // This is not required for inner router delegate because it does not
    // parse route
    assert(false);
  }

  void _handleBookTapped(Book book) {
    appState.selectedBook = book;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class FadeAnimationPage extends Page {
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimationPage({required LocalKey key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  Route createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      settings: this,
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, animation2) {
        var curveTween = CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn);
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation.drive(curveTween),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// Screens
class BooksListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Book> books;
  final ValueChanged<Book> onTapped;

  BooksListScreen({
    required this.books,
    required this.onTapped,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          for (var book in books)
            ListTile(
              title: Text(book.title),
              subtitle: Text(book.author),
              onTap: () => onTapped(book),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BookDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Book book;

  BookDetailsScreen({
    required this.book,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('Back'),
            ),
            Text(book.title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
            Text(book.author, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Settings screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working great. Thanks. But it seems too complicated. Will really appreciate if you give a brief idea of the logic behind this. Specially, how do you change the url in the browser upon clicking a different bottom navigation button. Thanks a bunch again.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching around for an answer to this for far too long now. I am 2 weeks and 13 iterations in on a project I'm working on and I'm still not satisfied with any of the MANY solutions I have seen/tried as every one of them have at least one major compromise I have ended up learning the hard way. I think I have spent enough time on this now to be able to say that flutter is just not cut out for this use case yet (not elegantly or simplistically and without breaking other flutter features anyway). They "support" the web, but currently, they are in no way optimised for it and it is very hard to create applications that mimic web behaviour. That is however unsurprising as they essentially state that themselves in their [Flutter 2022 Strategy](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTI9X2XHN_IY8wDO4epQSD1CkRT8WDxf2CEExp5Ef4Id206UOMopkYqU73FvAnnYG6NAecNSDo9TaEO/pub):

> Flutter shipped the first stable release of web support in 2021, and
> it remains too early to predict its ultimate success. Yet the web
> developer market is huge (10m+) and Flutter offers something
> distinctive for this audience compared to traditional DOM-based
> frameworks. As new technologies like CanvasKit, WebGPU, AOM, and
> WebAssembly with GC become available, Flutter is in a unique position
> of being able to target web apps designed for this new web generation.
> Its layered approach is well suited for targeting Canvas and WebGPU;
> Dart compiles to highly-optimized JavaScript today and will support
> WebAssembly in the future; and our consistent, Flutter's approachable
> API is a notable contrast to the complex “batteries not included” web
> ecosystem. ***Even if our role in the immediate future is a niche one,
> the web ecosystem is large enough that their niche is our growth
> opportunity.***

However, flutters cross-platform capabilities are no joke, hence why I have even bothered to spend so much time and effort on trying to find a solution to something that would have taken me less than 10 minutes to accomplish using my web background. I am sure this is the case for many others so here is an updated and improved version of the answers below that works with the latest version of flutter and null safety and also uses the built-in back buttons rather than the custom button implementation the other answers use:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const NestedRouterDemo());
}

class Book {
  final String title;
  final String author;

  Book(this.title, this.author);
}

class NestedRouterDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const NestedRouterDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NestedRouterDemoState createState() => _NestedRouterDemoState();
}

class _NestedRouterDemoState extends State<NestedRouterDemo> {
  final BookRouterDelegate _routerDelegate = BookRouterDelegate();
  final BookRouteInformationParser _routeInformationParser =
      BookRouteInformationParser();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Books App',
      routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
      routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
    );
  }
}

class BooksAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _selectedIndex;

  Book? _selectedBook;

  final List<Book> books = [
    Book('Stranger in a Strange Land', 'Robert A. Heinlein'),
    Book('Foundation', 'Isaac Asimov'),
    Book('Fahrenheit 451', 'Ray Bradbury'),
  ];

  BooksAppState() : _selectedIndex = 0;

  int get selectedIndex => _selectedIndex;

  set selectedIndex(int idx) {
    _selectedIndex = idx;

    // uncomment this line if you dont want to keep the selected book when navigating
    // between "settings" and "home" although if your doing this you should only really need 1 nested navigator for the whole app
    // if (_selectedIndex == 1) {
    //   selectedBook = null;
    // }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Book? get selectedBook => _selectedBook;

  set selectedBook(Book? book) {
    _selectedBook = book;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getSelectedBookById() {
    if (!books.contains(_selectedBook)) return 0;
    return books.indexOf(_selectedBook!);
  }

  void setSelectedBookById(int id) {
    if (id < 0 || id > books.length - 1) {
      return;
    }

    _selectedBook = books[id];
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class BookRouteInformationParser extends RouteInformationParser<BookRoutePath> {
  @override
  Future<BookRoutePath> parseRouteInformation(
      RouteInformation routeInformation) async {
    final uri = Uri.parse(routeInformation.location!);

    if (uri.pathSegments.isNotEmpty && uri.pathSegments.first == 'settings') {
      return BooksSettingsPath();
    } else {
      if (uri.pathSegments.length >= 2) {
        if (uri.pathSegments[0] == 'book') {
          return BooksDetailsPath(int.tryParse(uri.pathSegments[1])!);
        }
      }
      return BooksListPath();
    }
  }

  @override
  RouteInformation? restoreRouteInformation(BookRoutePath configuration) {
    if (configuration is BooksListPath) {
      return const RouteInformation(location: '/home');
    }
    if (configuration is BooksSettingsPath) {
      return const RouteInformation(location: '/settings');
    }
    if (configuration is BooksDetailsPath) {
      return RouteInformation(location: '/book/${configuration.id}');
    }
    return null;
  }
}

class BookRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<BookRoutePath>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<BookRoutePath> {
  @override
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  BooksAppState appState = BooksAppState();

  BookRouterDelegate() : navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>() {
    appState.addListener(notifyListeners);
  }

  @override
  BookRoutePath get currentConfiguration {
    if (appState.selectedIndex == 1) {
      return BooksSettingsPath();
    } else {
      if (appState.selectedBook == null) {
        return BooksListPath();
      } else {
        return BooksDetailsPath(appState.getSelectedBookById());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        MaterialPage(
          child: AppShell(appState: appState),
        ),
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        if (!route.didPop(result)) {
          return false;
        }

        if (appState.selectedBook != null) {
          appState.selectedBook = null;
        }
        notifyListeners();
        return true;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(BookRoutePath configuration) async {
    if (configuration is BooksListPath) {
      appState.selectedIndex = 0;
      appState.selectedBook = null;
    } else if (configuration is BooksSettingsPath) {
      appState.selectedIndex = 1;
    } else if (configuration is BooksDetailsPath) {
      appState.selectedIndex = 0;
      appState.setSelectedBookById(configuration.id);
    }
  }
}

// Routes
abstract class BookRoutePath {}

class BooksListPath extends BookRoutePath {}

class BooksSettingsPath extends BookRoutePath {}

class BooksDetailsPath extends BookRoutePath {
  final int id;

  BooksDetailsPath(this.id);
}

// Widget that contains the AdaptiveNavigationScaffold
class AppShell extends StatefulWidget {
  final BooksAppState appState;

  const AppShell({
    Key? key,
    required this.appState,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppShellState createState() => _AppShellState();
}

class _AppShellState extends State<AppShell> {
  late InnerRouterDelegate _routerDelegate;
  late ChildBackButtonDispatcher _backButtonDispatcher;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _routerDelegate = InnerRouterDelegate(widget.appState);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant AppShell oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _routerDelegate.appState = widget.appState;
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    // Defer back button dispatching to the child router
    _backButtonDispatcher = Router.of(context)
        .backButtonDispatcher!
        .createChildBackButtonDispatcher();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = widget.appState;

    // Claim priority, If there are parallel sub router, you will need
    // to pick which one should take priority;
    _backButtonDispatcher.takePriority();

    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Router(
          routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
          backButtonDispatcher: _backButtonDispatcher,
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: 'Settings'),
        ],
        currentIndex: appState.selectedIndex,
        onTap: (newIndex) {
          appState.selectedIndex = newIndex;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InnerRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<BookRoutePath>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<BookRoutePath> {
  @override
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  BooksAppState get appState => _appState;
  BooksAppState _appState;
  set appState(BooksAppState value) {
    if (value == _appState) {
      return;
    }
    _appState = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  InnerRouterDelegate(this._appState);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        if (appState.selectedIndex == 0) ...[
          FadeAnimationPage(
            child: BooksListScreen(
              books: appState.books,
              onTapped: _handleBookTapped,
            ),
            key: const ValueKey('BooksListPage'),
          ),
          if (appState.selectedBook != null)
            MaterialPage(
              key: ValueKey(appState.selectedBook),
              child: BookDetailsScreen(book: appState.selectedBook!),
            ),
        ] else
          const FadeAnimationPage(
            child: SettingsScreen(),
            key: ValueKey('SettingsPage'),
          ),
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        appState.selectedBook = null;
        notifyListeners();
        return route.didPop(result);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(BookRoutePath path) async {
    // This is not required for inner router delegate because it does not
    // parse route
    assert(false);
  }

  void _handleBookTapped(Book book) {
    appState.selectedBook = book;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class FadeAnimationPage extends Page {
  final Widget child;

  const FadeAnimationPage({required LocalKey key, required this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Route createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      settings: this,
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, animation2) {
        var curveTween = CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn);
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation.drive(curveTween),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// Screens
class BooksListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Book> books;
  final ValueChanged<Book> onTapped;

  const BooksListScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.books,
    required this.onTapped,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Books'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          for (var book in books)
            ListTile(
              title: Text(book.title),
              subtitle: Text(book.author),
              onTap: () => onTapped(book),
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BookDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Book book;

  const BookDetailsScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.book,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(book.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 200,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(book.title),
            subtitle: Text(book.author),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Settings'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Settings screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There are a few extra things worth mentioning:

1. This example above appears to break page transitions & hero animations (hence why the 'FadeAnimationPage' is used). I have found this [Flutter Navigator 2.0 for mobile dev: Nested navigators basics](https://lucasdelsol01.medium.com/flutter-navigator-2-0-for-mobile-dev-nested-navigators-basics-2dab6c55010e) which claims to have a solution to this however I have been unsuccessful in trying to implement it on this example
2. I have only used this example as it was the previous answer and was broken however I think that this is overkill. I think the most common use case for implementing something like this is to try and create persistent navigation for the web that still works with routing. For that, you only need one nested navigator for the entire app. I have also read that nested navigators can have significant performance implications as well so I would actually recommend not using more than 1 navigator unless you have a very specific reason why.
3. Finally, this example is just way too complicated and the flutter team know this. They have even started [Flutter User Experience Research (UXR)](https://github.com/flutter/uxr) to try and solve this however if I'm honest there is not as much activity on this as I would like to see. That is why I would recommend using a package such as GoRouter. They have a very well documented [nested navigation tutorial here](https://gorouter.dev/nested-navigation)