# How to detect change in the URL - Dart/Flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch a specific part from the youtube URL. For example:- if the user has put the following URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOjE7cQ0FkA

I would fetch the following part KOjE7cQ0FkA using the below method

```
          String url = urlController.text; // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOjE7cQ0FkA
          List urlList = url.split("=");
          String urlCode = await urlList[1];
```

but sometimes people copy the video link from mobile and this is how it would appear
https://youtu.be/KOjE7cQ0FkA  In such case, above code wouldn't work

So how can I detect which URL is put by the user and perform a split operation accordingly

Sorry, if my question sounds stupid but I hope you got an idea that what I'm trying to achieve here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this. One way would be to parse the URL (have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573567/parsing-a-uri-to-extract-query-parameters-with-dart)).

With this approach you could check if the query parameter `watch` is present -- if not the URL is probably in the mobile format.

---

Another approach would be to define a regex expression for the Video-ID (KOjE7cQ0FkA) part of the URL. That way you can extract the Video-ID regardless of the format of the URL. I would probably go with that approach.

Your regex could look like this: `([a-zA-Z]+(\d[a-zA-Z]+)+)`

I used [this](https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/?sampleText=2020-03-12T13%3A34%3A56.123Z%20INFO%20%20%5Borg.example.Class%5D%3A%20This%20is%20a%20%23simple%20%23logline%20containing%20a%20%27value%27.&flags=i&onlyPatterns=false&matchWholeLine=false&selection=) site to create the regex. You probably need to modify  it a little bit. Also if the ID has a fixed length that is a great criteria to filter by.

Comment: Thanks, mate! Accepted it as an answer :)